# Как языки программирования написанные на asm добиваться кроссплатформенность?

Tags: ассемблер

Я знаю, что под каждую архитектуру, assembler код - разный. Встаёт вопрос: неужели под каждую архитектуру, а их куда больше чем две, пишут свой транслятор для языка программирования?

Comment: Не весь компилятор, а только части,  зависимые от архитектуры (кодогенератор и платформозависимую оптимизацию (т.е. там, где  распределяем регистры и учитываем время исполнения конкретных инструкций). Но и на этом уровне многие платформы похожи и часть действий можно параметризовать).

Comment: Ну язык ассемблера весь зависим от архитектуры)

Comment: Конечно, зависим. Только после, скажем, 5-го ассемблера вы понимаете, что сходства больше, чем различий. Пожалуй, особняком стоит только чисто стековая (безадресная) архитекура. Зато она максимально близка к коду, выдаваемому парсером языка высокого уровня (который обычно на следующем этапе преобразуется в 3-х адресный псевдокод, а уже он раскладывается на реальные для архитектуры регистры и способы адресации)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да. Под каждую платформу пишут свой транслятор. Кроссплатформенность к примеру того же С++ обеспеченна тем что под него написано бесчисленное количеств компиляторов под бесчисленное количество платформ.